# How to enqueue wc-single-product for admin?

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, gallery

I want to enqueue wc-single-product from admin. I need to display single product gallery images slider from admin custom plugin page.`wp_enqueue_script( 'wc-single-product' );` This code is working for Frontend but not working for admin. Please help me.
Thank you

Comment: This is my Problem,
https://share.vidyard.com/watch/BDW3QDTDQrV9YZhUxvDTzd?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.